# How to secure persisted vuex data in a Vuejs SPA?

Tags: vue.js, single-page-application, vuex

I am building a single page app with vue js/vuex and Laravel backend, I need the users have different roles.  I am authenticating on the backend, and using a jwt token for API calls, I am not concerned that we will allow CRUD operations to be performed by a user without the appropriate permissions.  What I need to have is the ability for vue to know the role of the user and maintain statelessness without tampering.

I am using vuex-persistedstate with js-cookie and it works but the cookie is clear text and if I change the "role" in the cookie then refresh the page vuex uses the new value.  Obviously the data will come from the API and therefore when the token sent is for a user with role = user for data restricted to role = admin it will return 401.  Am I overthinking this?  If they really wont get, nor be able to change any data they aren't allowed to, just let the "hackerish" users do what they will?

Comment: As long as your backend is secure, and changing the role affects only frontend, I wouldn't care too much.

Comment: you might want to take a look over this one - https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-oidc